# Yii2: список категорий на всех страницах сайта (хочу поместить в `layout`)

Tags: yii, yii2

На сайте есть список категорий (в меню), которые будут браться из базы. Я решил поместить его в `layout`, так как он будет на всех страницах сайта.

Есть модель (Active Record), которая работает с БД. Где мне организовать работу с моделью, ведь контроллера специально для неё нет, а в виде как-то нелогично.

Порыскав по интернету, я нашел информацию, о том, что можно сделать виджет. Однако здесь как-то стал тогда другой вопрос. Я представляю виджет как автономную единицу. Модель категорий может понадобиться ещё где-нибудь, поэтому она находится в `app\models`. Если я буду её использовать в виджете, будет ли это правильным, я склоняюсь, что нет, так как виджет, по-моему должен быть автономным.

Подскажите как это правильно организовать, ведь это можно встретить почти на всех сайтах. Значит должен быть оптимальный вариант.

В Yii новичок.

---

Наглядный пример, если кто-то не поймёт о чём шла речь:

[image: Категории в меню]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно вы прочитали про виджеты. Именно для таких целей и используются виджеты, когда нужно вывести данные во View, которые нужно показывать на нескольких или всех страницах сайта.

[Почитайте тут](http://guide.yii2.org-info.by/guide-ru-structure-widgets.html) про виджеты, если ещё какие-то сомнения в необходимости их использовать.

Comment: Я прочитал уже всю документацию, перед тем как писать (как и советовали разработчики); правда, признаюсь :), некоторые моменты наискосок; да и чего уж таить :): некоторые чисто заголовок посмотрел, так как, думаю, пока они мне не понадобятся; но не суть, так как я сперва доки стараюсь смотреть а потом уже гуглить. Меня смущает тот факт, что я в виджете буду `use app\models\Category;`, то есть использовать внешнюю (назовём так) модель. Это нормально? Просто в силу пока ещё своей неопытности не хочу (выразимся так) говнокодить.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сделать из виджета, какой-то слишком обособленный кусок кода, а ведь это не так. Это такое же представление, только со специфическим выводом данных о чём и написано в той ссылке, что я дал: `В действительности, единственное его отличие состоит в том, что виджет представляет собой отдельный и удобный для распространения класс, в то время как представление - это обычный PHP скрипт, подходящий для использования только лишь в конкретном приложении.` А делать модели внутри виджета, вот это будет точно говнокодом :)

Comment: На это я как раз и обратил внимание: `удобный для распространения класс`. Я просто понимаю это как использование в другом приложении (на другом сайте например); но ведь если мы зависим от модели текущего приложения, то здесь нестыковочка выходит.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov вы немного путаете, мне кажется......есть понятие `Модуль` - это обособленная и независимая часть, которая в любой сайт можно впихнуть...то есть отдельная единица на уровне приложений.... а вот виджет - это обособленная часть, но внутри приложения, на уровне представления.... она может общаться с моделями, с какими-то еще частями, но при этом виджет можно выводить миллион раз на странице и в любой части и в любое время.....

Comment: `удобный для распространения класс` в данном контексте имеется ввиду, удобный для распространения на любых страницах внутри приложения. К примеру, вам нужно вывести не только ленту новостей в разделе новости, но и 3 последние новости на главную страницу и на страницу компании, и в этом как раз поможет виджет, который будет обращаться к той же модели `app\models\NewsArticle`, как и представление для вывода ленты новостей, только со своими параметрами запроса к базе.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, MasterAlex, всё — понял. Спасибо за разъяснения.